# Usage of typedef char (*fptr1())();

Tags: c, pointers

I am getting a compilation error message on this line (please see the code below):

```
   z = f;
```

The error message is

```
  lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

I am trying to utilize `typedef char (*fptr1())();`  But I am not successful.
What am I doing wrong?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 char f1() {
    return 'a';
 }

 char f2() {
    return 'b';
 }

 typedef char (*fptr)();
 typedef char (*fptr1())();

 //f is a function( char ) that returns a pointer to a function which returns a char.
 fptr f( char c ) {
     if ( c == 'a' ) 
        return f1;

     else 
        return f2; 
 }

int main() {
   fptr1 z;
   char c = 'a';

   fptr fp1 = f( c );
   printf( "%c\n", fp1());

   //z = f;        //error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   //fptr fp2 = z( c );
   //printf( "%c\n", fp2()); 
}
```

Comment: The `typedef` for `fptr1`, given your usage, would need to be `typedef fptr (*fptr1)(char)`  i.e. a pointer to a function that accepts a `char` as argument, and returns an `fptr`.    You can work out how to rewrite that `typedef` so it doesn't depend on `fptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second definition is wrong. You want a function pointer to a function that takes a char and returns `fptr` so you define it as

```
typedef fptr (*fptr1)(char);
```

Or if you don't want to use a typedef in a typedef

```
typedef char (*(*fptr1)(char))();
```

Comment: The function `f` is a function which returns a pointer to a function that returns a char.  So my understanding is `typedef fptr (*fptr1*()(char);`.  So there is a big difference with a minor syntax difference.

Comment: @Nguaial I don't know why you'd think that. Put what I wrote into your compiler and test it. I've also added what it would be without using typedef in a typedef.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work.  Here is a simplified question: How can I use an alias of the function `f`?  Like function pointers can be used as alias, I want to alias function `f`.

Comment: @Nguaial Define "didn't work." And if this isn't your exact code then edit the question to include that. Your current code works fine with the definition I gave.

Comment: `f()` is not function that returns a char.  It returns a function.

Comment: @Nguaial Yes. I know. And that's how it's defined in my answer. Which part of it doesn't work? What error does your compiler give you?

Comment: @Nguaial Here's an online version of your code. Compiling and running fine. http://ideone.com/bM13pp

Comment: Fantastic!!!! Clap clap!!! Standing ovation!!!  Great!!! Thanks!!! I forgot (char).  (00)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145303/discussion-between-nguai-al-and-sami-kuhmonen).